# Referring to NuGet packages from csx script

Tags: c#, scripting, nuget, roslyn

I am trying to write a C# interactive script (.csx) that needs to use a NuGet package, but I must be overlooking something fundamental because I can't get it to work.

I tried adding a `project.json` that refers to the package, and it gets installed into the global packages dir when I `nuget restore`, but it seems the `#r` directive does not look there. I failed to find a relevant documentation on how the `#r` directive work (most docs seem to deal with the similar but different project called ScriptCS).

How do you write a csx script that references NuGet packages?

Comment: Please, vote for this feature on uservoice: [Allow loading nuget assemblies-from csx](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18463615-allow-loading-nuget-assemblies-from-csx)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dotnet Script has support for referencing Nuget packages in CSX files:

```cs
#r "nuget: AutoMapper, 6.1.0"
```

https://discoverdot.net/projects/dotnet-script#nuget-packages-1

Comment: When the .Net core became a thing, we moved to Docker and the problem went away.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as it is the first correct one

Answer (score 6):

C# Interactive can't reference NuGet packages, but [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) can.

Comment: Thanks! I suspect this to be the case, but I failed to find any good source on this. How did you find out this to be the case?

Comment: I know of scriptcs but I am hesitant to introduce new non-nuget dependencies at the moment.

Comment: I know of scriptcs and have tried it. The last I tried, it was running the beta version of C# scripting and doesn't have all the goodies of C# 6.

Comment: What do you mean by "introduce new non-nuget dependencies"? scriptcs is kind of a runtime, not a library. To use csi (the command-line version of C# interactive) you need to install the build tools or Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 is already a dependency. I try to keep the number of dependencies down. Every odd tool that is required introduces complexity in setting up a new development machine, which has to be weighed against the complexity of writing the scripts. For example, CSI and PowerShell are already known to exist.

Comment: I understand your point. My personal view is that the Microsoft implementation is pretty much done while scriptcs will grow.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window#r) wiki entry has a note for the Interactive Window saying that you need to reference directly the NuGet DLL. So you could use the absolute path to the DLL in the global packages directory. It's not ideal, but should work.

Comment: But that is for the Interactive Window in VS, not the standalone CLI runner, right?

Comment: And even if referencing the global packages directory would work, I don't see how I could even write such a reference without access to environment variables. Even assuming the directory is not overridden, the default directory contains the user name.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple if you have ever worked with FSharp before, but the main
solution is:

```cs
#r "nuget:Newtonsoft.Json"
```

Above gets the latest package version. But if you want to specidy a version this works.

```cs
#r "nuget:Newtonsoft.Json,1.20"
```

If you happen to be working with external nuget sources, you should initialize that source with.

```cs
#i "nuget:http://example.com"
```

for sources on the web and

````cs
#i "nuget:C:\Nuget"
```for sources on your local file system
````

Answer (score 4):

Very simple from Visual studio UI:

1. Right click the project, Click `Manage NuGet Packages`

[image]

2. Selected the NuGet Package from the list in `Browse or Installed` tab and click the `nuget.org` URL

[image]

3. URL will lead to this webpage, Go to `Script and Interactive` tab, then simply click the copy button and paste it in your CSI in Visual studio or *.csx file

[image]

Comment: Yes, as @pwhe23 pointed out, the feature eventually came to C# interactive. 3-4 years after I needed it :)